# find a length of a triangle having two known sides and a median line

Tags: geometry

Can anyone help me solve this problem in a simple way? I used area of ACD+ABD=ABC to solve the problem, but it is quite complicated. Thank you very much!

Problem: Two sides of a triangle have lengths 25 and 20, and the median to the third side has length 19.5. Find the length of the third side.

[image]

Comment: [Stewart's Theorem](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Stewart's_Theorem) works well here.

Comment: Exactly, Stewart is good but the formula $4(\alpha)^2=2b^2+2c^2-a^2$ gives you $a^2$ directly (you have $\alpha$, $b$ and $c$)

Answer (score 1):

The length of a median to side $a$ is:
$$\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{2b^2 + 2c^2 - a^2}$$
Here $a=25$, $b=20$ and length of median = $19.5$.
So, 
$$19.5=\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{2(20)^2 + 2(25)^2 - a^2}$$
Squaring, 
$$1521 = 800 + 1250 - a^2$$
We get $a^2 = 529$ so $a=23$ as $a=-23$ is not possible.